# Inner join using ado.net is not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, asp.net-ajax

Inner join using Ado.net is not working properly. Please see the attached code and let me know. I am successfully receiving string array values in "values". I think I have some problem in my code itself.

```
public JsonResult searchdata(String[] values,String[] values1,String[] values2)
        {
            //String str;
            //for (int i = 0; i <= values.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    str = values[i];
            //    Console.WriteLine(str);
            //}

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                String str= "select accntname,BU,salesop,isdormant from fourth_page as fg"+
                                  " INNER JOIN linked as ld on ld.productid=fg.productid"+
                                   "INNER JOIN isdormant as it on it.productid=ld.productid"+
                                   "where fg.accountname in" + values;
                cmd.CommandText = str;
                SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString() + "" + dr[1].ToString() + "" + Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]) + "" + Convert.ToBoolean(dr[3]));
                }               

                connection.Close();
            }
            return Json(values);

        }
```

Comment: What is not working, What result are you expecting and what are you getting

Comment: Control is not entering into loop while debugging. I am getting 500 error in ajax call.

Comment: Which means your throwing an exception. Debug your code.

Comment: One question, is my inner join query correct or not?

Comment: How could I possibly know your table structure, but `"where fg.accountname in" + values;` could be an issue (but again, how do you expect anyone to guess what the value of `values`). And edit you question with the details of what is happening. And just comment out the code to confirm if its the issue.

Comment: Values is array of strings like "account1"," account2"

Comment: Query is retrieving values when I ran in sql database

Comment: Then its almost certainly the problem - the SQL should look like `WHERE fg.accountname IN ('account1', 'account2')"`

Answer (score 0):

`values` is an array, you cannot inject that to a query. you need to read each item from the array and use that in the in clause. The below code should work fine.

I also replaced the SqlDataAdapter with a SqlDataReader to query the data.

```
public JsonResult searchdata(String[] values)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Put your conn string here"))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
           var str= "select accntname,BU,salesop,isdormant from fourth_page as fg"+
                            " INNER JOIN linked as ld on ld.productid=fg.productid"+
                            " INNER JOIN isdormant as it on it.productid=ld.productid ";


            if (values != null && values.Any())
            {
             var items = values.Select((x, counter) => "@v" + counter);
             str +=string.Format(" where fg.accountname in ({0})", 
                                                             string.Join(",", items));

                var paramCounter = 0;
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v" + paramCounter, value);
                    paramCounter++;
                }
            }
            cmd.CommandText = str;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var c1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("accntname"));
                    result.Add(c1);
                }
            }                 
        }
    }
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```